# Error al compilar cordova: unexpected token

Tags: android, cordova

Buenas, ando luchando desde la mañana con el plugin de `cordova` de *local notifications katzer* ... Seguí al pie de la letra los pasos que están en `github` pero cuando le doy

> cordova build

`Android` me saca un gran error, espero puedan orientarme, y pues si no es mucho pedir también tengo duda de como usarlo puesto nunca lo he implementado, uso `cordova 5.4.1`

[image: cuando intento darle cordova build android][image: Error que da]

Comment: Parece que hay un caracter extraño en mitad de la palabra keyPassword. ¿si vas al archivo indicado, se ve bien?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro probablemente el archivo se vea bien pero el otro programa si lo detecta. Eldelaguila77, lo mejor sería cambiar ese archivo y reescribir la palabra Password para evitar problemas adicionales.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa tu `build.gradle` tienes un espacio en tu variable `keyPassword`

> unexpected token: Line 259, Column 66
>      gningConfigs.release.keyPassw               ord)){

debe ser algo como:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
          release {
              ...
              ...
              keyAlias "******"
              keyPassword "******"
         }
     }
}
```